# How to inject Maven profile value into properties file

Tags: java, maven

Little stuck here. I have a pom with 3 profiles. Theese profiles have different version name. I want to inject that version name into properties file when a specific profile is building.

My profiles:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <projectVersion>DEV</projectVersion>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <projectVersion>1.0.0-RC1</projectVersion>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <projectVersion>1.0.0-Final</projectVersion>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and filter.properties looks like this:

```
projectName = defaultName
versionName = defaultVersion
```

How to do that? Im building project by command:

```
mvn clean install -D profile_name
```

Comment: beware -D doesn't activate any profile, -P would do that though. Also the three profiles are active by default, is that what you want?

Comment: ahh, of course -P (my mistake!). My finall goal is to build a simple web app, that has one page with app name and app version. And version name in this web page depends on profile version name. My idea is to set profile version value into properties and from properties set it into jsp page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need to do is to add a new section to your `<build>` section of your POM file.

Like this:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

This will look inside the specified folder (`src/main/resources`) on the specified files `**/*.properties` and change the files when it encounters defined variables.

So in order to this work your propertie file must be this way:

```
projectName = ${defaultName}
versionName = ${defaultVersion}
```

Be aware with these variables name. Maven will replace it with the defined names by you or the names of the Maven structure like ${projectVersion} will be replaced by the `<version>1.0</version>` tag of your pom file.

So instead of using:

```
<properties>
     <projectVersion>1.0.0-Final</projectVersion>
</properties>
```

Change the name (and the version) of this variable to something else like:

```
<properties>
     <defaultVersion>1.0.0-Final</defaultVersion>
     <defaultName>someName</defaultName>
</properties>
```

On all your profiles.

And just run your maven command as:

```
mvn install -Pprofilename
```

Comment: Glad that it worked :) Consider in accepting it! if is the one of your choice.

Comment: Just to keep people from hunting, this was changed in SB 1.3.0. Here are the github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/… – mdo123

Answer (score 5):

Be careful with the profiles you shown. All of them are active by default and this is a problem because they all define the same maven property. Instead, you should mark only one as active by default.

You also don't show `<resources>` filtering to process `filter.properties`, so this can be a mistake, as well.

And a final though, you are controlling artifact version on maven profiles. I don't think it is a good idea. Please read about [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/).

Comment: can you please check https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues/1163#issuecomment-402485691, I couldn't get it working per this thread. thanks in advance.