# How to edit property file use Maven profile and take edited properties file during Maven build

Tags: java, pom.xml

I want to edit the properties file using Maven profile and then build project to run the test with edited property file using Maven build. I have following in my property file (`config.properties`)

```
browsername=${browser}
environment=${env}
```

I have tried all the solutions given and it's not working for me.

Comment: Check the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868310/how-can-i-change-a-properties-file-in-maven-depending-on-my-profile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject Maven profile value into properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289889/how-to-inject-maven-profile-value-into-properties-file)

Comment: yes. I have already tried those solutions ..but the tokens are not getting replaced. when I run "clean install -P<myprofilename>" the value is not getting updated to the config.property file

Comment: after adding <profiles> in <profile> section of pom.xml .. do I need to add any thing in to <build> section other then <resources>.. anything else needs to be added to <build section>