# Reference bamboo variable in Java code

Tags: java, bamboo

I have java app being built and deployed through Bamboo.
Is there way to populate, or insert into, java variable from bamboo deployment variable?

If something like below could work, is there additional steps that needs to be done within Bamboo configuration, or even within Java manifest file?

```
String myVariable = "${bamboo.myVariable}";
```

**[Bamboo Deployment Variable Configuration Screen]**

[image]

Comment: Simple answer is no. You can workaround this through other techniques though, such as bamboo creating a file through a script, or updating a content of a file in your java project source before building it, or even calling your program passing the variable as a parameter. But all that will need some more work other than just setting the variable value

Comment: Thanks Jorge for the response. This I guess is the official answer :) I may have to consider if this extra work is worth it. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Anyways why do you need the Bamboo to do that? If you have a maven project you can create profiles on your pom.xml file and instead of setting a variable in your bamboo task you can just build that task with a specific profile. That profile will have the desired value to your application and you can read it from a properties file. Take a look at this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34290417/460557

Answer (score 1):

If your custom variable is as `myVar` and bamboo default variable as `bamboo.buildNumber`, then they should be called as below.

Inside Bamboo Job ==> `${bamboo.myVar}` and `${bamboo.buildNumber}`

Inside Java Code ==>
`String myVal = System.getenv("bamboo_myVar");` and
`String buildNum = System.getenv("bamboo_buildNumber");`

Hope this simple and helps